# Connection reset issue with Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a Spring batch job which runs twice a day and it processes a huge amount of data from 90K to sometimes 100K policies a day. The batch is failing due to `Connection reset error`. We have an anti virus that is also running on the same server and this is just my analysis that when the anti virus is disabled the batch runs smoothly but when it is enabled the batch fails and we encounter a lots of connection reset errors on the log. I want to know if anyone has faced this issue before and can an anti virus causes network issue.

error log: `java.net.SocketExceptiopn: Connection reset`

Comment: `Connection reset` is sent from the database server. Which database server do you use?

Comment: I use SQL Server.

Comment: According to your description, the antivirus plays a role in the issue. It is probably disabling ports (or network connections) while scanning hence the Spring Batch process is not able to connect to the database server anymore. Not sure how to help from the Spring Batch side.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for your inputs. We disabled the anti virus and the job is working as expected. I wanted to find out what could be the affect of an anti virus you know what I mean.

Comment: I can vouch that anti-virus can really mess with you I had a AV service corrupt my downloaded maven dependencies. It literally would allow me to download jars and not warn me that it is corrupting them to such a point the jar was 1kb big. I lost a lot of hair that week.